# How to embed in Navigation Controller to a tabbar controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, tabbar

My initial view controller is a tab bar controller.I want to make the tab bar at top insted of bottom(which I have done using        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame) . I want to make a navigation bar appear above the tab bar . Can anyone please hep me to do this

Comment: I'm not shure if this is a good idea. Since we all expect it to be at the bottom.

Comment: I suggest, don't do that. Create your own bar below navigation bar (Add as subview to navigation bar).

Answer (score 1):

A UITabBar should always be at the bottom of the screen.
There is third party implementations of something that is similar to android tabs and might be what you are looking for.

Take a look at https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate your view controller with the one of these codes

```
let VC1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as! DemoViewController
```

OR

```
let VC2 = YourViewController()
```

If your view controller is defined at the interface bulider , then go with the first else , go with the second.

Now to construct view array for tabBarController I put NavigationController as the element with rootViewController being the VCs I instantiated .

```
let tab1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)

let tab2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)
```

Describe the tabBarItem images like this

```
tab1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "unselectedImage")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedImage")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal))
```

Finally describe the tabBar array

```
self.viewControllers = [tab1,tab2]  //This will create tabBar with 2 tabs
```

Your navigation controller will appear at the top with this. You can customize your Navigation Bar. For that see [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/).

Also don't forget to make your tabBarController the rootViewController in the AppDelegate. Otherwise you will go against Apple guidelines.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that make viewcontroller and use the UISegmentController to perform the Tab Bar Actions below the Navigation Bar..

thank you